# Bash regex doesn't match the pattern with \w and $

Tags: regex, bash, macos

I'm very new to Bash. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong. I tried the following regex pattern online and it works fine. But Bash script below refuses to match.

I need to extract the value of `status:` from the last line of a text block like so:

```
res=$(cat <<-EOM
Conducting pre-submission checks for my.zip and initiating connection to the Apple notary service...
Submission ID received
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
Successfully uploaded file
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
  path: path-to.zip
Waiting for processing to complete.
Current status: Invalid.....Processing complete
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
  status: Invalid
EOM
)

# Get status -- need word "invalid" from this line:  status: Invalid
status=""
regex='status:\s*(\w+)$'
[[ $res =~ $regex ]] &&
  status=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

echo "stat=$status"
```

Comment: For me it says `stat=Invalid`. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: I'm running it right now and it's getting an empty string... interesting

Comment: You're sure you run it with Bash? ZSH is now the default shell on Mac. I have `GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Hmm, with ZSH I get another error: `./so-status-regex.sh:18: read-only variable: status`

Comment: what version of bash are you running?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Oh, it could be ZSH. I'm saving it in a .sh file and just double-clicking it in the Finder.

Comment: I also get desired output with ZSH 5.9

Comment: The default Bash on MacOS does not support PCRE character classes. A Posix regex would be `'status:[[:blank:]]*([[:word:]]+)$'` Try that. Posix character classes [HERE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: Another issue: For `zsh` the variable `$status` is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: warning] **the `PCRE` like syntax `\w` is not supported in your version of `bash`**.

What I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# let's KISS: Keep It Simple Stupid
res='
Conducting pre-submission checks for my.zip and initiating connection to the Apple notary service...
Submission ID received
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
Successfully uploaded file
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
  path: path-to.zip
Waiting for processing to complete.
Current status: Invalid.....Processing complete
  id: 573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9
  status: Invalid
'

# Get status -- need this one:  status: Invalid
status=""
regex='status:[[:space:]]*([[:word:]]+)'
[[ $res =~ $regex ]] && status=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

echo "stat=$status"
```

##### Output

```
stat=Invalid
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `status:` | 'status:' |
| `[[:space:]]*` | any character of: whitespace characters (like \s) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `[[:word:]]+` | any character of: alphanumeric and underscore characters (like \w) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |

For some doc about `POSIX` *character classes*, see [`POSIX` spec's](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. It still doesn't work. It's very puzzling...

Comment: Show output of `echo $ZSH_VERSION`.

Comment: Do you have bash in /bin? Replace the shebang with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: @Cyrus: I'm getting `5.9`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Yes, I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: @c00000fd: How do you run your script?

Comment: @Cyrus: Double-click in the Finder.

Comment: @GillesQuénot: I tried your script one-to-one and got `stat=` like mine. I have no idea why it doesn;t work

Comment: Post edited, the regex was wrong for your version of bash. Tested on FreeBSD with close to same than MacOs

Comment: @GillesQuénot: OK, now you got it! Thanks. I'm wondering, why is it using its own version of regex syntax?

Comment: And is there a cheat-sheet for its regex?

Comment: You need a very recent bash to be able to use PCRE syntax `\s` and `\w`

Comment: Really! Wow. macOS has some old version installed by default? Anyway, where do you get the regex syntax for it from?

Comment: From my mind ?! =) `GNU bash, version 5.1.16` here and `FreeBSD` have `GNU bash, version 5.2.15`

Comment: :) OK, thanks. One last question, I see that if I want to match a GUID, like `573ebf8c-5434-4820-86c6-46adf01f81a9`, I can use `[[:xdigit:]]` to match hex digits, but how do I also match a dash? In other words, what shall I use instead of `([0-9A-Fa-f\-]+)`?

Comment: Use this : `[[:xdigit:]-]` Check `man tr`

Comment: For `zsh` the variable `$status` is read-only.

Comment: OP explicitly  used bash in code + tags dudes ;)